# How to show x axis values with date and month format in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng, angular2-highcharts

I am trying to show in the x axis values like date and month 03-02 instead of 03-02-2023

in the highcharts. But I do not know how to show it.

also need to show in the tooltip like Date 03-02-2023 | Quantity 20

If anyone know please help to find the solution.

[image]

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-cloning-barchart-ijk3ye?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can use `formatter` function for tooltip and change the date string in the way you want.

For example:

```
tooltip: {
  formatter: function(){
    const splittedDate = this.x.split('-');
    const dateAndMonth = splittedDate[0] + '-' + splittedDate[1];

    return `<p style="font-size:12px;margin:0px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;color:${this.series.color};">Date <strong>${dateAndMonth}</strong>| Quatity <strong>${this.y}</strong></p>`
  },
  ...
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-cloning-barchart-dabanu

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Comment: In the tooltip like Date 03-02-2023 | Quantity 20  and in the x-axis like 03-02

Comment: Please check the question

Comment: You have idea???

Comment: Hi @EMahan K, Sorry, I understood the problem in the opposite way. Here is the updated example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-cloning-barchart-kgkd6w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Can we use categories values dates like string?

Comment: Please check: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes#axis-types With category x-axis type, your dates are just plain strings.

Comment: I want to convert string dated to Date format. I am new for highcharts. So,Can you edit in this stackblitz?  https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-cloning-barchart-hxfrj7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @EMahan K, I am not quite sure what you want to achieve. It seems to be enough to combine the two previously provided functions, for example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-cloning-barchart-sksb25?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts